# Rewriting page urls in website

Tags: php, .htaccess

I created a simple website and some of the page urls are having the pattern "*.php".

I want to make my url `/home.php` as `/home`. Can I do this in `.htaccess` file?

I am adding my code here

```
<files campus_config.ini>
order allow,deny
deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</files>

<files student.ini>
order allow,deny
deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</files>

<FilesMatch (variables|mysql)\.php>
order allow,deny  
deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

sample url:
localhost/test/campus/login.php   (test is a folder ,campus is my project folder ,.htaccess file is in my project folder)

Comment: But when i tried the same in .htaccess file,it was giving me an error "/home is not found on this server" ,please help

Comment: A solution (not the best though): httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#forcetype

Comment: @Linblow ,i didn't get the solution,can you explain what you have mentioned ,Thanks for the response :)

Comment: @Vishnu are you running Apache or IIS?

Comment: @LIUFA, I am using Apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this line on in your `/test/campus/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test/campus/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: I am going to post my code here ,  RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule ^home\.php$ home [L]    ,do i need to enable content negotaiation module in apache?

Comment: Hi Anubhava,thanks ,I tried it .But still it is giving me the error "The requested URL /home was not found on this server".Evenafter changing the url,it is looking for home instead of home.php

Comment: What URL are you entering in your browser and what is location of this .htaccess file? Are there more rules?

Comment: I put .htaccess inside the project directory(present inside parent directory) .This is my entire code in .htaccess
<files campus_config.ini>
order allow,deny
deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</files>
<files student.ini>
order allow,deny
deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</files>
<FilesMatch (variables|mysql)\.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</FilesMatch>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

Comment: It is impossible to understand any code from comments. Edit your question and provide it there. Also is `projects` a sub directory under DocumentRoot?

Comment: Make sure above is placed in `/test/campus/.htaccess` and you send a URL of `http://domain.com/test/campus/home`

Comment: Yes ,I have placed it in campus/.htaccess and sent a url of  http://domain.com/test/campus/home .Confirmed both.

Comment: It should be directly placed in `/test/campus/.htaccess`

Comment: Because other lines are not mod_rewrite rules and don't depend on base path of .htaccess

Comment: I checked ,it is directly placed in /test/campus/.htaccess

Comment: So now you can open `http://localhost/test/campus/home.php` but `http://localhost/test/campus/home` gives 404?

Comment: Yes anubhava , I tried to open http://localhost/test/campus/home.php ,it is redirected to http://localhost/test/campus/home and giving me 404

Comment: Yes that redirection is as per first 301 rule and that worked fine. Not sure why 2nd one didn't work for you

Comment: Can you try placing `Options -MultiViews` line on top of your .htaccess

Comment: ok comment out both `RewriteCond` lines before last rule and retry

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called URL rewriting. This is normally done by application server usually Apache or IIS (on windows). [how to do it in Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html). On windows it depends on version (6-8) of IIS used.

Comment: ,sorry for late reply,I am using Apache